# Cross-concatenate two matrices in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Given two matrices, for example

```
[1 2] and [5 6]
[3 4]     [7 8],
```

is there a way to concatenate them to get the following matrix?

```
[1 2 1 2]
[3 4 3 4]
[5 5 6 6]
[7 7 8 8]
```

Comment: `np.block([[a, a], [b, b]])`

Comment: @percusse Is there a tensorflow alternative to it? Sorry for putting numpy also as tag.

Comment: @RaghuramVadapalli there is no typo in the last two raws? Shouldn't be they like first 2?

Comment: @asakryukin, no, there isn't any typo. Every column of first matrix must be concatenated with every column of second one

Comment: @percusse Sorry, your numpy code is also wrong. It doesn't give desired output

Comment: I misread the last two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NumPy based approach**

Using `array-initialization` with [`broadcasted-assignment`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def assign_as_blocks(a,b):
    m1,n1 = a.shape
    m2,n2 = b.shape
    out = np.empty((m1+m2,n2,n1),dtype=int)
    out[:m1] = a[:,None,:]
    out[m1:] = b[:,:,None]
    return out.reshape(m1+m2,-1)
```

**To let use tensorflow tools, a modified version would be :**

```
def assign_as_blocks_v2(a,b):
      shape1 = tf.shape(a)
      shape2 = tf.shape(b)
      m1 = shape1[0]
      n1 = shape1[1]
      m2 = shape2[0]
      n2 = shape2[1]
      p1 = tf.tile(a,[1,n2])
      p2 = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(b, 1),[1,1,n1]), [m2,-1])
      out = tf.concat((p1,p2),axis=0)
      return out
```

**Sample runs**

Case #1 (Sample from question) :

```
In [95]: a
Out[95]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [96]: b
Out[96]: 
array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]])

In [97]: assign_as_blocks(a, b)
Out[97]: 
array([[1, 2, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 3, 4],
       [5, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 8]])
```

Case #2 (Generic shaped random array) :

```
In [106]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3))
     ...: b = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,5))

In [107]: a
Out[107]: 
array([[5, 0, 3],
       [3, 7, 3]])

In [108]: b
Out[108]: 
array([[5, 2, 4, 7, 6],
       [8, 8, 1, 6, 7],
       [7, 8, 1, 5, 8],
       [4, 3, 0, 3, 5]])

In [109]: assign_as_blocks(a, b)
Out[109]: 
array([[5, 0, 3, 5, 0, 3, 5, 0, 3, 5, 0, 3, 5, 0, 3],
       [3, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3, 3, 7, 3],
       [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7],
       [7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8],
       [4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5]])
```

Comment: Cool!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you give tf version for the same? I am having trouble using similar thing in tf

Comment: Trying with tile but tile repeats entire array. Please let me know if you were able to figure it out

Comment: That worked. Can you add actual tf code in answer. I got something like this - https://pastebin.com/zmbfSi36. Please confirm and modify

Comment: @RaghuramVadapalli Feel free to edit this post with that code. Thanks.

Comment: Done! Please review

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> b = [[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> np.r_[np.kron([1,1],a),np.kron(b, [1,1])]
array([[1, 2, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 3, 4],
       [5, 5, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 8, 8]])
```